# inserting all column value into a variable mysql

Tags: php, mysql

sorry for the simple question, but I'm not sure about answer:
this is part of function, I want to insert "name, password , type , callerid"  insert into $value

```
if ($key == 'NewIpPhone'){
        set_flag_sip($user_id);
        $q="select name,secret,type,callerid from cc_sip_buddies where id_cc_card='$user_id'";
        if($res=mysql_query($q))
        {
            if($row=mysql_fetch_row($res))
            {
                $value="name".return $row[0];   
                $value.="password".return $row[1];
                $value.="type".return $row[2];
                $value.="callerid".return $row[3];
                return $value;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        return 0;
        }
    }
$sql="INSERT INTO newrequest (id,[key],value,sent,time) VALUES ('0','$key','$value','0', NOW())";   

$retval = mysql_query( $sql);
if(! $retval )
{
 die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

is it correct ?

Comment: $key == 'NewIpPhone' may be?

Comment: Query Looks ok to me. Besides the formating-issue with your variables. Put them outside your string... See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO newrequest (id,[key],value,sent,time) VALUES ('0','".$key."','".$value."','0', NOW())";
```